# bootstrap-datepicker.es.min over all

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm facing problems with the bootstrap-datepicker.es.min. The component is not over all but it's down the menu bar. [image]

Is there a way to put over this bar?
I've used this but doesn't work:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Init code:

```
<input type='text' id='fechainicial'
name='fechainicial'
class='fechainicial form-control input-sm m-bot15'
placeholder='Fecha inicial' readonly='' data-datepicker="true" />
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">  
  </span>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".fechainicial_").datepicker({
    language: "es",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please add the full code of the bootstrap-datepicker? Including the JavaScript Part that initializes it? Also I don't really understand whats wrong with the screenshot.

Comment: You might wanna set the zIndex greater than the zIndex of the nav-bar. [See here](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1820)